# Can I trust aws-cli to re-upload my data without corrupting when the transfer fails?

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, aws-cli

I extensively use S3 to store encrypted and compressed backups of my workstations. I use the `aws` cli to sync them to S3. Sometimes, the transfer might fail when in progress. I usually just retry it and let it finish.

My question is: Does S3 has some kind of check to make sure that the previously failed transfer didn't leave corrupted files? Does anyone know if syncing again is enough to fix the previously failed transfer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual files uploaded to S3 are never partially uploaded. Either the entire file is completed and S3 stores the file as an S3 object, or the upload is aborted and S3 object is never stored.

Even in the multi-part upload case, multiple parts can be uploaded but they never form a complete S3 object unless all of the pieces are uploaded and the "Complete Multipart Upload" operation is performed. So there is no need worry about corruption via partial uploads.

Syncing will certainly be enough to fix the previously failed transfer.

Comment: That is a reasonable assumption, but have you reviewed the code?  I haven't.  Unless the (sadly, optional) `Content-MD5` mechanism is used correctly by aws-cli, S3 could perfectly store a corrupted-in-transit upload.  Complete-Multipart-Upload can also assemble a perfect copy of a corrupted upload if the built-in safety mechanism isn't implemented. Or exceptions could be swallowed whole. Some failures are blatantly ignored by aws-cli, such as permission denied errors on the local filesystem.  I have nothing but good things to say about S3 itself, but the cli gives me no confidence.

Comment: The question was about a failed transfer leaving corrupted files, not about all the ways in which corruption can occur. We could discuss corruption 1) on client disk, 2) in client memory, 3) in transit, 4) in S3 memory, and 5) on S3 storage, etc.. I did not believe any of that was relevant to the question.

Comment: To me, the question is about whether the aws-cli utility properly validates uploads and handles errors.  If it doesn't properly handle things that can go wrong and are within its sphere of influence, then those things seem relevant to the answer.  If a client cannot be trusted to obviously and clearly fail when failures occur that it should be able to detect, that's a problem, and my impression is that the code in aws-cli is too optimistic that things will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, looks like AWS CLI does validate what it uploads and takes care of corruption scenarios by employing MD5 checksum.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-faq.html

*The AWS CLI will perform checksum validation for uploading and downloading files in specific scenarios.
The AWS CLI will calculate and auto-populate the Content-MD5 header for both standard and multipart uploads. If the checksum that S3 calculates does not match the Content-MD5 provided, S3 will not store the object and instead will return an error message back the AWS CLI.*